# Laravel 7 edit route not calling the controller method

Tags: laravel, routes

Hi I have following route in web.php all route are working properly except edit .
I can not understand what are happening .
Any help will highly appreciated .

```
    Route::get('/manage-users','Admin\User\UserController@index')->name('manageuser');
    Route::get('/add-users','Admin\User\UserController@create')->name('adduser');
    Route::post('/store-users','Admin\User\UserController@store')->name('storeuser');
    Route::get('/edit/{$id}/user','Admin\User\UserController@show');
    Route::post('/delete-user','Admin\User\UserController@deleteUser');
```

Comment: whats the error ?

Comment: What is the exact URL request
?

Comment: error is 404 | Not found

Comment: see my answer @Rishi

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
Route::get('/edit/{$id}/user','Admin\User\UserController@show');
```

to

```
Route::get('/edit/{id}/user','Admin\User\UserController@show');
```

You don't need `$` for route params for more info [visit](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#required-parameters)

Thanks

Comment: thank you so much , I was trying to figure out since 1 hours . Thanks @Salman Zafar

Answer (score 0):

In routes you shouldn't use `$`:

```php
    Route::get('/edit/{id}/user','Admin\User\UserController@show');
```